# How to store same library version compiled differently in Linux?

Tags: linux, qt, shared-libraries, .so

I have two different Qt projects, one of which needs to be compiled with Qt 4.8 and the other being compiled with Qt 5.4. Both need to use the library  QDeviceWatcher compiled in accordance to their versions (i.e. the app under Qt 5 should have QDeviceWatcher compiled for Qt 5 and the one using Qt 4.8 needs QDeviceWatcher compiled with Qt 4.8).

The problem is that, under Linux, the .so library files are supposed to be located in the same "global" folder, `/usr/local/lib`. Since I'm working on both projects, I'ld have to have both groups of .so files located in that folder - what simply is not possible given that they have the same name and the last addition would simply overwrite the previous one.

As for now what I'm doing is each time I change the project to be compiled, I update the library files with the compilation I need, but that is obviously undesirable.

Is there any way to counter this problem?

The only two ways I came across was to create a fake new version of the library (currently is 2.0.0, so I could create version 2.0.1) and compile each lib version for one different Qt version (but of course that would be messy, I mean, it's a fake version!) or to locate the .so files in a directory close to the project so the files would be looked after there instead of in the global dir `/usr/local/lib`. But that, seems to me, breaks down the whole idea of having the library available globally for all and new applications. And Google didn't help me with this.

Comment: Can you give specific info about the library file names that's causing you problems ? On my machine the Qt4 and Qt5 libraries have different names, so if I want to link to version 4 of Qt I use `-lQtCore` and for version 5 I use `-lQt5Core`. Note that your `.so` file should be a symlink pointed to a particular version, so if both your Qt4 and Qt5 libraries are named the same, it might just be during compilation/linking that you have a problem - once linked, the executable should be linked to the proper version.

Comment: @nos it seems you misunderstood my problem: it's not between the Qt libs, but the QDeviceWatcher lib compiled with different Qt versions.

Comment: Well then the QDeviceWatcher `.so` files should have had a different name depending on whether it's compiled towards Qt 4 or Qt5 as is customary for many external Qt libraries - but since that library isn't built that way you'll need to place them it in different directories, one for Qt4 one for Qt5 and instruct your application to look for libraries in the matching directory - or have someone update the build system of QDeviceWatcher to produce different library names.

Answer (score 1):

Given that `QDeviceWatcher` is a 3rd party app what I would do is install it outside of the  `/usr/local/lib` folder and into the project directory instead, and update my `.pro` to point to it directly.